# Avoid CSS inheritance

Tags: css

I have this CSS style:

```
span
{
    font-family: Book Antiqua;
    clear: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I want to remove vertical-align on span inside a div called divDetail. In other words, I want this style on any span inside divDetail:

```
#divDetail span
{
    font-family: Book Antiqua;
    clear: right;
}
```

How can I do that? How can I remove vertical-align style?

Thank you!

Comment: Just for neatness, put quotes around font-names which contain spaces. I guess it will work in most browsers, but according to specifications ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-family-prop ) they should be quoted. Good practice etc. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `vertical-align: baseline`.